# How do I prevent shrinking in Model-based testing?

Tags: f#, fscheck

Here's the example of model-based test in FsCheck:

```
let spec =
  let inc = { new Command<Counter, int>() with
                    override __.RunActual counter = counter.Inc(); counter
                    override __.RunModel m = m + 1
                    override __.Post(counter, m) = counter.Get = m |@ sprintf "model: %i <> %A" m counter
                    override __.ToString() = "inc" }
                           
  let dec = { new Command<Counter, int>() with
                    override __.RunActual counter = counter.Dec(); counter
                    override __.RunModel m = m - 1
                    override __.Post(counter, m) = counter.Get = m |@ sprintf "model: %i <> %A" m counter
                    override __.ToString() = "dec" }
  
  { new ICommandGenerator<Counter,int> with
      member __.InitialActual = Counter()
      member __.InitialModel = 0
      member __.Next model = Gen.elements [inc;dec] }
```

**How do I disable shrinking of commands for this test?**

Comment: I assume you're asking how to prevent shrinking the **number** of commands used, rather than how to prevent shrinking of the actual command objects themselves? For example, by default, FsCheck will try to shrink `[inc; inc; dec; inc; inc; dec; dec; dec]` (7 commands) to `[inc; inc; inc; dec]` (4 commands).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent FsCheck from shrinking the number of commands used (see my question above), you can convert the spec to a property that disables shrinking:

```ml
let property =
    let generator = Command.generate spec
    let shrinker _ = Seq.empty   // disable
    Command.toPropertyWith spec generator shrinker
Check.Quick(property)
```

This allows FsCheck to generate command sequences that are longer than necessary. E.g. `[inc; inc; dec; inc; inc; dec; dec; dec]`.

Comment: To be clear either way FsCheck will generate the longer sequences. What is being disabled here is the phase after generation, where FsCheck will try to find a shorter sequence (starting from a long failed sequence) that still fails the test.